# MongoDB and Morphia - Traditionnal id (Long) instead of ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

**Background:**

My REST service project was started up by using Hibernate. I use id (Long) in domain class as part of the identifier in rest url, for example:

http://abc.com/customer-50, where 50 is the Long id.

The Hibernate Annotated class is as below:

```
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
}
```

Now I need to migrate our design to Mongodb. The natural choice is using Morphia, which is an entity framework.

**Problem:**
In Morphia, the id field is ObjectId

```
@Id private ObjectId id;
```

This will cause problem because:
1. It is not auto-increment, i.e. http://abc.com/customer-50, http://abc.com/customer-51, http://abc.com/customer-52.

Now it become http://abc.com/customer-4d1b4687a6d5437619000000

1. I will need to change all the reference classes from long to objectId.
2. Is it possible to keep the original design (which uses Long id, instead of ObjectId)?

Thanks!

Comment: MongoDB has sequences: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers

Comment: One issue with using this method is that you will require an extra round-trip to the server whenever you need to create a new Entity. It will impact concurrency and throughput of your system. It might be noticeable but there is a cost... just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at  <s>https://code.google.com/p/morphia/source/browse/trunk/morphia/src/main/java/com/google/code/morphia/utils/LongIdEntity.java</s> <s>https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/utils/LongIdEntity.java (link updated)</s>
https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/xyz/morphia/utils/LongIdEntity.java (updated again)

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Comment: The link is once again invalid.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated it again. This might also tell a bit of a story about the stability of Morphia...